# Descent properties for rational topological cyclic homology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Descent properties can be extremely useful for studying  $\operatorname{TC}$ (topological cyclic homology), since it is a sheaf in many well behaved topologies.

I was wondering what is known about $\operatorname{TC}_\mathbb{Q}$ in this regard.

It seems clear to me that any site which has $\operatorname{TC}$ as a sheaf, and is also given in terms of a cd-structure will have $\operatorname{TC}_\mathbb{Q}$ as a sheaf, but I am particularly interested in the étale topology.

Comment: What do you call $TC$?

Comment: @OlivierBenoist topological cyclic homology

Comment: Any localizing invariant valued in rational spectra satisfies étale descent, by an argument of Thomason; see the paper by Clausen, Mathew, Naumann, Noel. (Note that TC is not a localizing invariant in the strong sense which requires that it commutes with filtered colimits, but that is not necessary for Thomason's argument.)